# How to design a remote controller for an android application?

Tags: android, automation

I've written an android application, and I'd like to make it controllable to other machines by sending HTTP request to the device that run my application. I've written a tiny HTTP server and made it start when my application is started. I know I could translate HTTP requests and send messages to various activities to perform UI operations, that need to add listener to all my activities. But in order to make the remote controller code reusable, I hope separate remote controller code from existing application code and thus I need to find a way to make as less as change to the application code to make it be remote controllable.

Could anyone share your ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I dont get what you are asking tbh but in one of application that my friend create, he just implement a mouse pointer which works from any android phone. With that application he can manage to use the android tv.

When he was implementing that app, he took advantage of socket programming and send messages from remote controller, in that situation a phone, to other device and fetch the data in there. In my opinion if you follow such a manner you just dont need to apply so many changes in your other applications. It is all communication in the end.